# Cómo combinar dos órdenes en una misma línea de comando?

Tags: r, string, data

Tengo un dataframe con una columna que contiene nombres y debo hacer dos cosas:

1- añadir a cada nombre FR al comienzo del mismo

2- que cada nombre tenga una longitud de 21 caracteres. En caso de no tenerlos, que rellene los espacios al final del mismo con la letra C.

Estoy intentado ejecutar la siguiente orden simultáneamente, nada más que por ahorrar líneas de comando:

`df$nombre<-paste0("FR", df$nombre)<-stri_pad_right(df$nombre,21,"C")`

Me da el error

> Error in paste0("FR", df$nombre) <- stri_pad_right(df$nombre),  :
>   target of assignment expands to non-language object

Hay alguna manera de ejecutar dos o más órdenes en la misma línea? Cómo debe hacerse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error está en que estas intentando asignar un valor a algo que R no puede interpretar como una variable, en este caso `paste0("FR", df$nombre)` a la que intentas asignarle el retorno de `stri_pad_right(df$nombre,21,"C")`.

Para escribir todo en una sola línea, aunque en mi opinión no te aporta ni claridad ni performance, hay dos formas de hacerlo:

#### Concatenar instrucciones con `;`

```
library(stringi)
s <- 'texto'

s <- paste0("FR", s);s <- stri_pad_right(s,21,"C")

s
[1] FRtextoCCCCCCCCCCCCCC"
```

En este caso, simplemente asignamos a `s` la primer operación y luego volvemos hacer lo mismo con la siguiente, pero ambas instrucciones en la misma línea, separadas por `;`

#### Anidar funciones

```
library(stringi)
s <- 'texto'

s <- stri_pad_right(paste0("FR", s),21,"C")

s
[1] FRtextoCCCCCCCCCCCCCC"
```

En este caso en particular, como la salida de una función, es la entrada de otra, puedes "anidar" las dos llamadas y que todo se resuma a una sola línea.

#### Usar pipe `%>%`

```
library(magrittr)
library(stringi)

s <- 'texto'

s %>% paste0("FR", .) %>% stri_pad_right(21,"C")

s
[1] FRtextoCCCCCCCCCCCCCC"
```

El `%>%` es una clausula muy interesante que te aporta el paquete `magrittr` permite reconstruir una llamada como la anterior, es decir anidada, en una invocación más compacta y ordenada. No voy a extenderme, hay mucho para hablar del pipe, te recomiendo que lo investigues.

```
library(magrittr)
library(stringi)

s <- 'texto'
s %>% paste0("FR", .) %>% stri_pad_right(21,"C")
```

Comment: Genial el %>%, no se me había ocurrido y también pienso que es la mejor solución. Muchas gracias!